# How to count() each variable automatically

Tags: r

I am cleaning some data and like to use the `count()` function in dplyr to look at unique values of every variable.
Is there a way to do this automatically? Right now I am using this method:

```
df %>% count(variable1)
df %>% count(variable2)
df %>% count(variable3)
...
```

I would like something that returns all of them without me having to repeat the line of code and type in each variable. I thought about trying to have R recognize all the column names and automatically fill them in but I'm not sure where to start. If I just add variables together, say

`df %>% count(variable1, variable2)`

I get counts by both of those variables when I want individual tables for each variable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What format do you want the counts to be in?  Do you want a new data frame with variable name and count?  If so what will the rows and columns to hold?

Comment: @itsMeInMiami  Ideally an individual table for every variable but I don't need to store these counts anywhere. So one column is the variable and the other column is counts for each value of the variable. The exact output you'd get from the individual count() calls in the question, but all in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you want to count `am`, `gear`, and `carb` from `mtcars`. You can apply the function `table()` on each variable by `map()`, which returns a `list` object.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mtcars %>%
  select(am, gear, carb) %>%
  map(table)

# $am
#  0  1 
# 19 13 
# 
# $gear
#  3  4  5 
# 15 12  5 
# 
# $carb
#  1  2  3  4  6  8 
#  7 10  3 10  1  1
```

**`base` Version :**

```
lapply(mtcars[c("am", "gear", "carb")], table)
```

---

In addition, you can use `summary()`, which counts factor variables.

```
mtcars %>%
  select(am, gear, carb) %>%
  mutate(across(.fn = as.factor)) %>%
  summary

#  am     gear   carb  
#  0:19   3:15   1: 7  
#  1:13   4:12   2:10  
#         5: 5   3: 3  
#                4:10  
#                6: 1  
#                8: 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can use a `tidyverse` approach to solve your issue. You want to get the counts for each variable in your dataset (Please next time add a sample of `df`). You can get something close to what you want using data in long format. I will show you an example with `mtcars` data. I will choose some variables that display classes so that they can be summarised with counts. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
data("mtcars")
```

I will select some categorical variables with next code, then I will reshape to long. Finally, I will use `summarise()` and `n()` (used for counting) with `group_by()` to determine the counts:

```
#Code
mtcars %>% select(cyl,vs,am,gear,carb) %>%
  #Format to long
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  #Group and summarise
  group_by(name,value) %>%
  summarise(N=n())
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   name [5]
   name  value     N
   <chr> <dbl> <int>
 1 am        0    19
 2 am        1    13
 3 carb      1     7
 4 carb      2    10
 5 carb      3     3
 6 carb      4    10
 7 carb      6     1
 8 carb      8     1
 9 cyl       4    11
10 cyl       6     7
11 cyl       8    14
12 gear      3    15
13 gear      4    12
14 gear      5     5
15 vs        0    18
16 vs        1    14
```

As you can see all the variables are showed with their respective groups and counts.

Comment: @Sara It returns just for one variable! But in a global dataframe for all the variables. Try `mtcars %>% count(am)` and see the output is included in the final data I shared in the answer!

Comment: @Sara If you think this answer was useful you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer. It is up to you :) and in that way you continue encouraging people to help others!

Comment: I removed the select() line because I want all variables and changed the summarise() line to just count() to shorten it.

Comment: @Sara you can try that also just be sure to have in long format the data with `pivot_longer()`

Comment: Good idea! By the way, `group_by(name, value) %>% summarise(N = n())` is equivalent to `count(name, value, name = "N")`, which saves you one pipe line.

Answer (score 1):

a simple solution would be to use `sapply` or `lapply` with `table`

```
sapply(df,table)
```

This will return you a list of count tables for each of the columns for dt. You can always pass in a subsetted dataframe to get the count for your variables of interest.